# How to create a Excel like interface?

Tags: wpf, excel

I am new to WPF and need to create a application that import a excel file and then accroding to some database values have to manipulate some cell values programmatically.

Also i need to display and edit the file like in MSExcel.

I have found some third party tools, but i am looking for .net framework libraries.

please help me to find some related links or posts to create the same.

Comment: Why not just launch EXCEL, and run it from your application. See my answer posted earlier here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351183/excel-macro-open-sheet-in-background-and-execute-analysis-in-background-sheet/16351454#16351454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WPF [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is probably the .NET Framework Library component that comes closest to your requirement of "like MSExcel".

If you need something more fancy, your options are

- third party libraries,
- automating Excel or
- [writing an Excel add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668205.aspx).

Comment: can you just provide me some third party example application links. That wil be more helpful, 'coz i have nly a shrt perd to do this. Thank You Heinzi.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have personal experience with them, so I cannot recommend any one in particular.